# [ERROR] could not find joint_state_publisher

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, this is my first time here.
i'm using indigo and gazebo2.2 in ubuntu14.04 to simulate our robot.

when i was following the tutorils,had a problem with this [page](http://wiki.gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo).

it says to launch these two,to control the rrbot.

`roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch`
`roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch`

but when i launch `roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch`  this error occcurs.

> [ERROR] [1414305408.351300373, 6.335000000]: Could not load class joint_state_controller/JointStateController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin joint_state_controller/JointStateController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
> [ERROR] [1414305408.351370497, 6.336000000]: Could not load controller 'joint_state_controller' because controller type 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' does not exist.
> [ERROR] [1414305408.351394983, 6.336000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
> [ERROR] [1414305409.424146233, 7.403000000]: Could not load class effort_controllers/JointPositionController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin effort_controllers/JointPositionController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
> [ERROR] [1414305409.424214515, 7.403000000]: Could not load controller 'joint1_position_controller' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist.
> [ERROR] [1414305409.424239188, 7.403000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
> [ERROR] [1414305410.492735676, 8.466000000]: Could not load class effort_controllers/JointPositionController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin effort_controllers/JointPositionController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
> [ERROR] [1414305410.492799660, 8.466000000]: Could not load controller 'joint2_position_controller' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist.
> [ERROR] [1414305410.492830507, 8.466000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
> Warning [Publisher.cc:134] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/pose/local/info, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.

does anyone solved this problem?

thanks ,

Ryo.

ps

ros_controllers package cause other catkin_make problem, so i tried this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-control ros-indigo-ros-controllers
```

but another error occurs

> [ERROR] [1414652580.407543556, 4.281000000]: Exception thrown while initializing controller joint1_position_controller.
> Could not find resource 'joint1' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
> [ERROR] [1414652580.407647493, 4.281000000]: Initializing controller 'joint1_position_controller' failed
> [ERROR] [1414652581.462573639, 5.332000000]: Exception thrown while initializing controller joint2_position_controller.
> Could not find resource 'joint2' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
> [ERROR] [1414652581.462662991, 5.332000000]: Initializing controller 'joint2_position_controller' failed

I checked  `rrbot_control.yaml`and `rrbot.xacro`, but of course there was a state about joint1 and joint2.

could you tell me where to check for?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195944/%5Berror%5D-could-not-find-joint_state_publisher/) by [Ryo_Amano](https://answers.ros.org/users/20586/ryo_amano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think i solved the problem.

the problem was rrbot.xacro

in the state

replace

`<joint name="joint1"/>`

with

```
 <joint name="joint1">
  <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
</joint>
```

and all error was cleared

thanks for your help.

RYO

---

Originally posted by [Ryo_Amano](https://answers.ros.org/users/20586/ryo_amano/) with karma: 26 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1